# Convert a number-word (String) to its Integer Value

Tags: java, arrays, converters

**EDIT:** right, I forgot to state the problem -- which is the fact that I get `0` as an output.

**CONTEXT**

My program aims to take a user-inputted number-word (1- 99) and output it as an integer (i.e. thirty-four = 34). I can't figure out where the error in my code is and need help:

```
Scanner scInput = new Scanner(System.in);
String word = scInput.nextLine(); //number in word-form (i.e. twenty six)

char[] charArray = word.toCharArray();//string to char array for word^
int divider = 0; //position of hyphen/space in charArray
```

All 2-word numbers are comprised of a tens value & a ones value. Assuming proper syntax [english], the word before the hyphen/space `divider` is the tens and the word following `divider` is the ones.

**ARRAYS**

```
//word values - components & syntax (1-99)

//ONES
public static final String[] wONES = {"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine"};

//TENS
public static final String[] wTENS = {null,"twenty","thirty","forty","fifty","sixty","seventy","eighty","ninety"}; 

//TEENS
public static final String[] wTEENS = {"ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen","fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"};
```

I've organized all the word-components into 3 different arrays: ones, tens, and teens.

```
//equivalent integer-array  of above String arrays

//ONES
public static final int[] nONES = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

//TENS
public static final int[] nTENS = {0,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90};

//TEENS
public static final int[] nTEENS = {10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19};
```

I created 3 other arrays that are the same as the above three arrays, except they store the integer values.

**CODE**

Here I separate the user-inputted String into two sections: the tens and the ones. So if the number was 72: 70 = tens and 2 = ones.

```
int tensValue = 0; //number's tens value (i.e. 30)
int onesValue = 0; //ones value (i.e. 3)

        char[] tensArray = null; //array storing tens section of word (before divider)
        for (int u = 0; u < divider; u++){
            tensArray[u] = charArray[u];
        }
        String tens = new String(tensArray); //convert char array to String


        char[] onesArray = null; //array storing ones section of word (after divider)
        for (int u = divider + 1; u > divider && u < charArray.length; u++){
            onesArray[u] = charArray[u];
        }
        String ones = new String(onesArray);

        //searches for matches in String array for tens
        for(int u = 0; u < wTENS.length; u++){
            if(tens.equals(wTENS[u])){
                tensValue = nTENS[u];
                total += tensValue;

            }
        }

        //searches for matches in String array for ones
        for(int u = 0; u < wONES.length; u++){
            if(ones.equals(wONES[u])){
                onesValue = nONES[u];
                total += onesValue;
```

Comment: Well for starters `char[] tensArray = null;` should be something like `char[] tensArray = new char[10];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an interesting approach to this problem.  A couple of things to change:

1. I don't see where you set your divider index.
2. You seem to be doing a lot of work with character arrays, so I'm guessing you're coming from a different language.  Sticking with Strings will work fine.
3. You don't address the "teens".  This looks like a simple oversight.

I've added those fixes while attempting maintain the original approach:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {

    Scanner scInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word = scInput.nextLine();

    int total = 0;
    int tensValue = 0; //number's tens value (i.e. 30)
    int onesValue = 0; //ones value (i.e. 3)

    int divider = word.indexOf('-');
    String tens = null;
    String ones = null;
    if (divider != -1) {
        tens = word.substring(0, divider);
        ones = word.substring(divider + 1);
    } else {
        ones = word;
    }

    //searches for matches in String array for tens
    if (tens != null) {
        for (int u = 0; u < wTENS.length; u++) {
            if (tens.equals(wTENS[u])) {
                tensValue = nTENS[u];
                total += tensValue;
            }
        }
    }

    //searches for matches in String array for ones
    for(int u = 0; u < wONES.length; u++) {
        if (ones.equals(wONES[u])) {
            onesValue = nONES[u];
            total += onesValue;
        }
    }

    // if a "teen" override what's in total
    for(int u = 0; u < wTEENS.length; u++) {
     if (ones.equals(wTEENS[u])) {
         total = nTEENS[u];
     }
    }

    System.out.println(total);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your current code you are doing `char[] tensArray = null;` which should be something like `char[] tensArray = new char[10];` or else you end up with `NPE`.

It might not be most efficient but here is a simple and better approach to your problem.

1. Read the line and split it on white space (assuming you are separating your words by a space).
2. Search each of the tokens you get after split in the above lists and add the corresponding number (same index) to your answer.
3. Print the answer.

Here is the code snippet:

```
class Main
{
    public static final String[] wONES = {"one","two","three","four","five","six",
                                          "seven","eight","nine"};
    public static final String[] wTENS = {"ten","twenty","thirty","forty","fifty","sixty",
                                          "seventy","eighty","ninety"}; 
    public static final String[] wTEENS = {"eleven", "twelve", "thirteen","fourteen",
                                           "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", 
                                           "nineteen"}; 

    public static final int[] nONES = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    public static final int[] nTENS = {10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90};
    public static final int[] nTEENS = {11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19};

    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Scanner scInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String word = scInput.nextLine();
        int answer = 0;

        /* Assuming you are giving space between words */
        for(String s : word.split(" ")) {
            /* Scan wONES */
            for(int i = 0; i < wONES.length; i++) {
                if(wONES[i].equalsIgnoreCase(s)) {
                    answer += nONES[i];
                    continue;
                }
            }

            /* Scan wTENS */
            for(int i = 0; i < wTENS.length; i++) {
                if(wTENS[i].equalsIgnoreCase(s)) {
                    answer += nTENS[i];
                    continue;
                }
            }

            /* Scan wTEENS */
            for(int i = 0; i < wTEENS.length; i++) {
                if(wTEENS[i].equalsIgnoreCase(s)) {
                    answer += nTEENS[i];
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Result: " + answer);
    }
}
```

Input:

```
thirty four
```

Output:

```
34
```